# singular values in svd calculation using numpy

Tags: numpy, svd

I have a question for following

```
A = array([
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
[21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]])
print(A)
# Singular-value decomposition
U, s, VT = svd(A)
```

For above “s” should be of shape(10,) as we have 10 features, but instead of (3,) is shown. Sample output is shown below I am confused. Kindly explain, why we go (3,)

```
(3, 10)
U shape (3, 3)
s shape (3,)
VT shape (10, 10)
```

Let us consider another example

```
A = array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
print(A.shape)
# Singular-value decomposition
U, s, VT = svd(A)
Here “s” shape is shown as (2,)
```

Here output is shown below

```
(3, 2)
U shape  (3, 3)
s shape (2,)
VT shape  (2, 2)
```

I am not getting why there is difference in shape. Kindly expalin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), a matrix *A* of shape *(m x n)* is decomposed into

- a unitary matrix *U* of shape *(m x m)*
- a rectangular diagonal matrix *Sigma* of shape *(m x n)*
- a unitary matrix *V* of shape *(n x n)*

*Sigma* contains all singular values on its main diagonal. Since a matrix of shape *(m x n)* only contains *min(m, n)* elements on its main diagonal, there are only *min(m, n)* singular values.